# How to switch turn in socket programming java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a battleship game in java, and using socket programming.

I can chat and the message is comming to the JTextArea. But the issue is that I need to shoot, and when the user have shoot the user cannot shoot again. The user have to wait for the other user to make the shoot.

The code I have now the user can only get one shoot each, where to i need to place yourTurn = true ??

This is what I got on the Client code :

```
 public void run() 
  {
      try 
      {
          try
          {
              out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
              in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());


            out.flush();
            checkStream();


        }
        finally
        {
            socket.close();
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(socket);
    }
}
private void checkStream() 
{
    while(true)
    {
        recieve();
    }   
}
private void recieve() 
{
    if (in.hasNext()) 
    {
        String message = in.nextLine(); 


        if (message.contains("S> ")) 
        {

            System.out.println("shoot " + message);

            if (yourTurn) 
            {
                yourTurn = false;
            }

            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Det er ikke din tur endnu");
            }

        } 
        else 
        {
            //Is a chat message
            Gui.consoleTextArea.append(message + "\n"); 
        }



    }
}

public void Send(String msg)
{
        out.println(Gui.name + " : " + msg);
        out.flush();        

    Gui.textFieldSend.setText("");

}
```

Can someone give me a hint what to do?

Comment: What is this `try`-`try`-block good for?

Comment: Eclipse want a try try block

Comment: @tinaw25 Unliely. More likely you misunderstood what it told you.

Comment: It want    try   - try or an throw exception.

Comment: Than why not single `try-catch-finally` ??

Comment: I have change that know with an     single try-catch-finally

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with the switch turn issue??

Answer (score 1):

**You're setting the turn variable backwards.**

When you receive a message, you need to set this value to `true`, because now it is your turn.  When you send a message, you need to set this value to `false`, because it is no longer your turn.

In your code, when you receive a shot, you check if it is their turn and make it not their turn.  That is backwards.  This is where you want to check if it is not their turn and make it their turn.  Then you want to add some code to where you send out the shot to only allow this action if it's your turn, and doing so makes it no longer your turn.

Comment: Everytime I press my send button, It will run the recieve(); method and it will make my turn true.